# Line break not working when concatenating strings

Tags: php, line-breaks, string-concatenation

I was googling a lot about this problem but didn't see any answer that could help me. 
For example i have next line of code:

```
$row ['technischgereed'] =  "The quotation is not technically completed \n" . $separatedArray ; 
$row ['technischgereed'] =  "The quotation is not technically completed \r\n" . $separatedArray ;
$row ['technischgereed'] =  "The quotation is not technically completed <br/>" . $separatedArray ;
$row ['technischgereed'] =  "The quotation is not technically completed". "\n(or <br> or \r\n)" . $separatedArray ;
```

So i want to have something like the following

```
The quotation is not technically completed
Planned:Kitchen
In execution:Bedroom
Done:Basement
```

Instead of this i get everything in a same row.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nl2br($row['technischgereed']), it will change /n to `<br />`

Besides that, I think you should use .= for the next message, I only see the equal sign, which means that every new equal overwrites the previous instead of adding to it.

Comment: Actually these four lines of code are interpretation of various cases i was trying(with <br>,\n or \r\n).So it's just one line.My mistake sorry,looks a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

\n will only be visible in the source as a newline. Use `<br />` in stead, or use `nl2br()` on your `$row ['technischgereed']` when echoing it out to convert your newline characters to `<br />`.